# Pass argument only when length is greater than zero

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am calling a method on dynamodb's `query` command, and the property `FilterExpression` is optional, or it takes a non-empty string.

Is there a way for me to only pass `FilterExpression` as a parameter only when the length of `filter > 0`?

```
def select(filter='')
    response = self.dynamodbConnection.query(
        FilterExpression=filter
        # Other arguments here
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def select(filter=''):
    if len(filter) > 0:
        response = self.dynamodbConnection.query(
            FilterExpression=filter
        )
    else:
        response = self.dynamodbConnection.query(# Other arguments here)
```

or

```
def select(filter=''):
    args = {}
    if len(filter) > 0:
        args['filter'] = filter
    response = self.dynamodbConnection.query(**args)
```

Comment: The second method is what I was looking for!